# Why none type error in traversing tree when I have covered these cases?

Tags: python, tree

I am writing a iterative solution to traversing a binary tree 'in-order':

```
class Treenode:

     def __init__(self,val = 0, left = None, right = None ):
            self.val = val
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
class Solution:
    def PostorderTraversaliterative(self,root):
        stack = []
        stack.append(root)
        output = []

        if not root:
            return []

        while stack:
            curr = stack.pop()
            output.append(curr.val)

            if curr.right:
                stack.append(curr.left)

            if curr.left:
                stack.append(curr.right )

        return output
```

For some reason when I run it, I am getting an error: 'NoneType object has no attribute 'val'?'For the output.append(curr.val) line.

I don't understand why I am getting this error, as I thought the if curr.right and if curr.left deals with the cases where either are None.
And if not root deals with the case where the root is None.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the sample data.  What is the value/structure of ```root```?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: Thanks Tomerikoo, the first link is a big help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inverted `curr.left` and `curr.right` in your if statements:

```py
            if curr.right:
                stack.append(curr.left)   #  curr.right instead
            if curr.left:
                stack.append(curr.right)  #  curr.left instead
```